# Command not found error in Makefile

Tags: c, linux, gcc, makefile

I am trying to write a Makefile. This is what I have written.

```
CC='/buildtools/toolchain/wr-x86/3.0FCScg/bin/i586-wrs-linux-gnu-gcc --sysroot=/buildtools/toolchain/wr-x86/3.0FCScg/sysroot'
IDIR =../../../include
CFLAGS=-I$(IDIR)

LDIR =../../../../../../../../.debug/lib.out/public/
LIBS= -lmylib1 -lmylib2 -lmylib3

myexec: my_code.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o myexec my_code.c
```

This when run throws an error

```
make: /buildtools/toolchain/wr-x86/3.0FCScg/bin/i586-wrs-linux-gnu-gcc --sysroot=/buildtools/toolchain/wr-x86/3.0FCScg/sysroot: Command not found
```

However, it works when I run the compile command manually in terminal.

```
export CC='/buildtools/toolchain/wr-x86/3.0FCScg/bin/i586-wrs-linux-gnu-gcc --sysroot=/buildtools/toolchain/wr-x86/3.0FCScg/sysroot'
$CC -I ../../../include -L ../../../../../../../../.debug/lib.out/public/ -lmylib1 -lmylib2 -lmylib3 -o myexec my_code.c
```

Comment: Don't put quotes around it in the makefile.

Comment: And options should be in `CFLAGS`, not in `CC`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Removing the quotes helped. Also, is the way I am linking to libraries correct?

Comment: What happens when you run `'/buildtools/toolchain/wr-x86/3.0FCScg/bin/i586-wrs-linux-gnu-gcc --sysroot=/buildtools/toolchain/wr-x86/3.0FCScg/sysroot'` in your terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the definition in the `Makefile` to this:

```
CC=/buildtools/toolchain/wr-x86/3.0FCScg/bin/i586-wrs-linux-gnu-gcc --sysroot=/buildtools/toolchain/wr-x86/3.0FCScg/sysroot
```

With the quotes, `make` uses the whole definition as the name of the executable to look for.

The reason it works when you define `CC` outside the `Makefile` is the rules for handling quotes are different for the shell and the Makefile.

A more common convention is to use `CFLAGS` for all compilation flags.  As a matter of facts, I strongly suggest you add `Wall -W` to your `CFLAGS` definition.

Regarding the libraries, you should expand `$LIBS` after the source and object files on the `cc` or `ld` command line.